# Cross join InterBase get duplicate record based on condition

Tags: sql, firebird, interbase

I am working with InterBase at the moment by Using Firebird. I need to get a record twice with a condition, but every time I run the query I keep getting an error message. Is there a way to get around the cross join in InterBase? Will there be a simpler way to get around to add this logic to the query. It seems like Firebird wont accept the cross join.

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME, LAST_NAME, CACODE

FROM EMPLOYEESTABLE 

(
SELECT 889 AS CACODE, 8592-265-44444 AS STANDARDCACODE
UNION ALL 
SELECT 695 AS CACODE, 8554-265-44578 AS STANDARDCACODE
) C
```

Comment: Please do not use all capitals in title, it makes it harder to read and is considered shouting. Also Firebird != InterBase they have diverged in the past 18 years and are no longer the same nor compatible. So are you using Firebird, or are you using InterBase?

Comment: You may also want to specify the exact error message you get (although I think it will be something like a _token unknown (_ as your statement is syntactically incorrect (you are missing a join clause between `FROM EMPLOYEESTABLE` and the next 'table').

Comment: the query never uses STANDARDCACODE column

Answer (score 3):

Select always needs `from`. The table `RDB$DATABASE` returns 1 row with the database name so we can use that. I think you are looking to do this:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME, LAST_NAME, CACODE

FROM EMPLOYEESTABLE, 

(
SELECT 889 AS CACODE, '8592-265-44444' AS STANDARDCACODE FROM RDB$DATABASE
UNION ALL 
SELECT 695 AS CACODE, '8554-265-44578' AS STANDARDCACODE FROM RDB$DATABASE
) C
```

Comment: Personally, I would prefer an explicit SQL-92 style `CROSS JOIN` over a SQL-89 implicit join.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   889 AS CACODE, 
   /* '8592-265-44444' AS STANDARDCACODE, >>unused<< */ 
   EMPLOYEE_NAME, 
   LAST_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEESTABLE 

UNION ALL

SELECT 
   695 AS CACODE, 
   /* '8554-265-44578' AS STANDARDCACODE, >>unused<< */ 
   EMPLOYEE_NAME, 
   LAST_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEESTABLE
```

Who need joins with such a simple query :-D

Comment: I'd assume the query from the question is simplified, and then using a cross join instead may make more sense.